# SQL db2 query on ambiguity

Tags: db2

Is there away I use the column name as it is while I select and solve the ambiguity issue starting from and where or join

e.g

```
Select account,currency from acc acc
Join card card on acc.account=card.prmaccount
```

In this query 'currency' column is available in both the tables, so 'currency' is ambiguous in the select-list.

Problem:

Account and currency is hard coded in program so I cannot 
Use Alais name. But I can write my join or any other 
Starting at the 'from' clause via the front end tool.

Is there any way to do this

`Select account,currency` —- hardcoded in program 
From `acc acc` onwards -- i can write my own using front end

Comment: Usually databases have a metatable. You may find this useful. https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7323.table-metadata

Comment: This is not a Db2 problem, it's a functional restriction in your front-end tool - it should let you qualify column-names with an alias in the select to facilitate joins between tables that have the same column names.   If you have permissions to create a view then you may be able to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select account, currency from acc 
where account in (select prmaccount from card)
```

For a query that simple the execution plan should be identical to the one with the explicit join.